# Titan XP vs Quadro P400 GPU in Pytorch

Tags: performance, time, cuda, gpu, pytorch

I gave the the two GPUs on my machine a try and I expected the Titan-XP to be faster than the Quadro-P400. However, both gave almost the same execution time.

I need to know if PyTorch will dynamically choose one GPU over another, or, I myself will have to specify which one PyTorch will use, during run-time.

Here is the code snippet used in the test:

```
import torch
import time

def do_something(gpu_device):
    torch.cuda.set_device(gpu_device)  # torch.cuda.set_device(device_num)
    print("current GPU device ", torch.cuda.current_device())
    strt = time.time()
    a = torch.randn(100000000).cuda()   
    xx = time.time() - strt
    print("execution time, to create 1E8 random numbers, is ", xx)
    # print(a)
    # print(a + 2)

no_of_GPUs= torch.cuda.device_count()
print("how many GPUs are there:", no_of_GPUs)
for i  in range(0, no_of_GPUs):
    print(i, "th GPU is", torch.cuda.get_device_name(i))
    do_something(i)
```

Sample output:

```
how many GPUs are there: 2
0 th GPU is TITAN Xp COLLECTORS EDITION
current GPU device  0
execution time, to create 1E8 random numbers, is  5.527713775634766

1 th GPU is Quadro P400
current GPU device  1
execution time, to create 1E8 random numbers, is  5.511776685714722
```

Comment: Are you *certain* that your `do_something` function is actually creating those random numbers on the GPU, rather than on the CPU and then transferring the results to the GPU?

Comment: @talonmies ..shouldn't this line ... a = torch.randn(100000000).cuda()  ... create the random numbers on the GPU?

Comment: I don't know much about torch, but just on Python syntax alone, no. I read that as "create a tensor in the default memory space filled with unform random numbers and copy that tensor to the GPU". And the default is, I am guessing, the CPU memory

Answer (score 3):

Despite what you might believe, the lack of performance difference which you see is because the random number generation is being run on your host CPU not the GPU. If I modify your `do_something` routine like this:

```
def do_something(gpu_device, ongpu=False, N=100000000):
    torch.cuda.set_device(gpu_device)
    print("current GPU device ", torch.cuda.current_device())
    strt = time.time()
    if ongpu:
        a = torch.cuda.FloatTensor(N).normal_()
    else:
        a = torch.randn(N).cuda()
    print("execution time, to create 1E8 random no, is ", time.time() - strt)
    return a
```

and run it two ways, I get *very* different execution times:

```
In [4]: do_something(0)
current GPU device  0
execution time, to create 1E8 random no, is  7.736972808837891
Out[4]: 

-9.3955e-01
-1.9721e-01
-1.1502e+00
     ......     
-1.2428e+00
 3.1547e-01
-2.1870e+00
[torch.cuda.FloatTensor of size 100000000 (GPU 0)]

In [5]: do_something(0,True)
current GPU device  0
execution time, to create 1E8 random no, is  0.001735687255859375
Out[5]: 

 4.1403e+06
 5.7016e+06
 1.2710e+07
     ......     
 8.9790e+06
 1.3779e+07
 8.0731e+06
[torch.cuda.FloatTensor of size 100000000 (GPU 0)]
```

i.e. your version takes 7 seconds and mine takes 1.7ms.  I think it is obvious which one ran on the GPU....

Comment: Thanks! This time it is really on the GPU. 
However, the Quadro is still faster than the Titan Xp, not sure why(BTW, I am using Cuda version 8.0)! 

0 th GPU is TITAN Xp COLLECTORS EDITION-
execution time, to create 1E8 random no, is  6.318092346191406e-05,,,,,,,
1 th GPU is Quadro P400, 
execution time, to create 1E8 random no, is  4.482269287109375e-05

Comment: The CUDA API is asynchronous. Once again, you may not be measuring the actual execution time, I don't know how pytorch works internally so I don't know if that is the case. Try using a profiling tool like nvprof to look at the execution time